# split file sentences into words

Tags: java

can anyone help me please?

I'm trying to split the `sentences[]` into `words[]`. But  it shows `Syntax error on token "j", delete this token`...

My code is:

```
try
{
    int j;
    String paragraph = sample.readFileString(f);
    String[] sentences = paragraph.split("[\\.\\!\\?]");
    for (int i=0;i<sentences.length;i++)
    {  
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(sentences[i]);  
        for( j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
            String  word[j]=sentences[i].split(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: Type in the sentence which you are trying to split .

Comment: Can you also add the full error log?

Answer (score 1):

```
String  word[j]=sentences[i].split(" ");
          ^^^^^^^^
```

this is not a valid `String` or `String array` declaration.

Comment: hi friends,how can i split one dimensional[] of sentences into two dimensional[][] of words.

Answer (score 0):

`String.split()` returns an array. So you have to change

```
String word[j] = sentences[i].split(" ");
```

to this

```
String[] word = sentences[i].split(" ");
```

Comment: i got the answer.but how can i split one dimensional[] of sentences into two dimensional[][] of words.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of for loop with j variable use:

```
String[] words = sentences[i].split(" ");
```

For multidimensional array:

```
String paragraph = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non varius nisi. In at erat est, sit amet consectetur est. ";
String[] sentences = paragraph.split("[\\.\\!\\?]");

String[][] words = new String[sentences.length][];

for (int i=0;i<sentences.length;i++) {  
   words[i] = sentences[i].trim().split(" ");
}

System.out.println(words[0][1]); //[sentence][word] - it would be second word of first sentence
```

Comment: i got the answer.but how can i split one dimensional[] of sentences into two dimensional[][] of words.

Answer (score 0):

split looks like `String[]split(String regex)`[split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

so change your `String  word[j] = sentences[i].split(" ");`
to

```
String  word[] = sentences[i].split(" ");
```

Comment: i got the answer.but how can i split one dimensional[] of sentences into two dimensional[][] of words.